# libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap: Error

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

When i execute my app,i get this error on the debugger:

[image: error]

in this line of code:

```
if (!([photo.photoDescription isEqualToString:[photoDictionary[PHOTO_DESCRIPTION] description]]))
```

the code inside the if is never execute. what does this error means? and how can i fix it?
however the app doesn't  crash and continuos to execute, but the code inside the if is not execute.
Thanks